# Advanced Module Manager Assignments

Tags: module, module-display, joomla-3.9

Using Joomla 3.9.11 and [AMM 2.7.1](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/advancedmodulemanager/faqs#how-to-prevent-the-url-assignment-also-matching-urls-you-don-t-want)

I have a blog with the url `www.example.com/news`

I need to display some modules on the right hand side of this page, but **only** on that exact URL.

If the URL contains anything after `/news` then the modules should not be displayed. For example `www.example.com/news/my-great-story` should not display the modules.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In URL assignments section:

- Set the option to **Include**
- In URL matches enter `/news/?$`
- Enable **Use Regular Expressions**

*The `/?` part is used for the case your `/news` page is also loading via `/news/` and you need to show the module in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, add URL include regex

`news($)`

Comment: This post has been automatically flagged as Low Quality.  Please be more generous with your answers.  I personally do not see why capturing the end of string anchor would be advantageous.